# Two tooltip points on one path in d3.js line chart

Tags: html, d3.js

I've made this simple line chart in d3, but as well as showing the tooltip data for mouseover, I would also like to display the data for where the blue dotted line of the tooltip intersects with the data path in the first instance.

For intsance at the link below, if the mouse hovers at 2012, data for 2005 would show at the first intersection between the tooltip line and the data path.

http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/49f04076adbec7e2c2f9

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked example, you would want to search for months with CPI intervals that contain the CPI value that is currently displayed.  So, create a list of such intervals, with references to the month that contains them, then find matching intervals on hover.

Something like this, for example (untested):

```
// after loading data
var cpi_intervals = [];
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    cpi_intervals.push({
        cpis: d3.extent([data[i-1].cpi, d.cpi]),
        date: d.date
    });
  }
});

...

// function to find months containing specified cpi
function monthsContainingCPI(cpi) {
  return cpi_intervals.filter(function(d) {
    return cpi >= d.cpis[0] && cpi < d.cpis[1];
  }).map(function(d) {return d.date;})
}
```

If needed, you can improve the performance of the monthsContainingCPI function by using a more complex data structure, like an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), to store and access the CPI intervals.

Comment: That makes sense, I've done as suggested but nothing is showing up (nor are the errors in the console). Is that because I need to then write something to make the other values show up on mouseover? At the moment it's still the one set.

Comment: Yes, this lets you find the dates, but you could write the code to display it in different ways. It will probably be similar to the .y3 and .y4 nodes that are currently used.

Comment: Thanks unable to test this as not proficient enough to work out how to amend code to display additional CPI values on mouseover, any insight as to how to write the code would be helpful if possible. Have tried creating a second focus for cpis but that hasn't worked.